# How to check which animation is playing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a PlayerMovement and I have some problem with checking if my character is idle, running or sprinting. As you can see i can't quite figure out how to "Do something" if my characters animation is idle, running or sprinting and i tab space.

```
if(anim.Play("Idle") && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
             //Do something
        }
```

I want to be able to "Do something" if 1 animation out 3 is in action.

Comment: Do you mean idle and (tab + space) are pressed down simultaneously?

Comment: When i mean tab space i'm reffering to pressing the spacebar

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].  If `anim` doesn't have an API to get the current activity, you may have to create a `GetActivity` function that calls anim.Play()` with each of the possible activity strings and returns an appropriate enumeration, so you can do a `select (GetActivity(anim))...` and take the appropriate action `if Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)`.

Answer (score 2):

**[`Animation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html)**

What you seem to use here [`Animation.Play(string name)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Play.html) returns

> In cases where the animation can not be played (for example when there is no default animation or no animation with the specified name), the function will return `false`.

This is not what you want to use as it restarts your animation every frame and returns always true if a clip named `Idle` exists ;)

So in case `anim` is an [`Animation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html) you rather want to check using [`Animation.IsPlaying(string name)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.IsPlaying.html)

```
if (anim.IsPlaying("Idle") && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    // Do something
}
```

---

**[`Animator`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html)**

In case `anim` is an [`Animator`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html) you can use [`GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(int layerIndex)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo.html) which returns an [`AnimatorStateInfo`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorStateInfo.html) where you can use [`IsName(string name)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorStateInfo.IsName.html)

```
if (anim1.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Idle") && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: And also is possible to attach a StateMachineBehaviour script directly on the state. The event `OnAnimatorUpdate()` will execute only when the animation is playing, if @matty want to explore far away xD

Comment: @Windgate for the `Animator` yes. For the `Animation` which OP seems to be using this is not possible ;)

Comment: @Windgate actually absolutely nothing bad about the `Animation`. Why do you think Unity retracted the obsolete state? It is very usefull in cases you do not want/need complex `Animator` state machines but rather want to simply enable and disable animations ;) Checkout e.g. [this Youtube Talk about exactly this subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1972&v=W45-fsnPhJY&feature=emb_logo)

Comment: You are right with that, my point is I have bad memories of programming full character controllers with Animation, years ago, still hurts :S